# NSPredicate Creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

how shall I create an NSPredicate to that test whether a NSString start with some pattern, say "AAA"?
Thank you very much!
I tried to read Apple's reference but could not understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", @"AAA"];
```

And if you want to find all matching strings from array:

```
for(NSString *n in [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", n);
}
```

And answer to your comment about 'c' and 'd' characters etc:

> **SELF** is in this case NSString object
>
> **BEGINSWITH[]** explanation not needed, I think.
>
> "String comparisons are by default case and diacritic sensitive. You can modify an operator using the key characters **c** and **d** within square braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively" (quote from Apple's [Predicates Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", Your_text];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please explain what those terms mean? Like what is "name"? Is it a keyword? And also for "CONTAINS" and "cd"